# What does the '$' mean in python environment?

Tags: python

So stupid question but I read things like:

```
$ pip install check-manifest,
$ check-manifest --create,
$ git add MANIFEST.in,
```

all the time. It's definitely a python command that I run from the cmd, but what does the '$' mean?
it's everywhere and but with no explanations. Does it just represent flags or something?

Comment: $ signifies its a linux command (normal user), its a terminal symbol after which command is written. With root user $ changes to #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is nothing. In Linux it appears before any command in terminal.
It indicates user access.

`$` is normal user

`#` is root user

You don't need to put that when executing anything.

Comment: Technically it's a *shell* prompt. The terminal is just the program that hosts the shell.